# efficient merge when static data

Tags: r, merge

I have some static data stored in the data frame `static_data`. The goal is to merge the `data` with the `static_data` in order to obtain the `output`

```
data <- data.frame(A = c("a","b","c","d","e"),B=c("a","b","b","e","e"))

static_data <- data.frame(I=c("a","b","c","d","e"),Info=c(1,2,3,4,5))

output <- data.frame(A = c("a","b","c","d","e"),B=c("a","b","b","e","e"),
                     AI=c(1,2,3,4,5),BI=c(1,2,2,5,5))
```

my code is the following

```
colnames(data) <- c("I","B")
temp <- merge(data, static_data,by="I)
```

and so one. what's the best way to have an efficient code?

Comment: @MrFlick I agree with your proposal. but first you have to merge using column A and then column B. I want to avoid renaming as much as possible

Comment: Do you really need your data in "wide" format. It would be easier to melt your data and then do the merge once.

Comment: yes I need to keep the wide format in the sense that A and B represent IDs that are linked together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mg <- merge(data, static_data, by.x = "A", by.y = "I")
cbind(mg, BI=merge(data, static_data, by.x = "B", by.y = "I")[,3])

#  A B Info BI
#1 a a    1  1
#2 b b    2  2
#3 c b    3  2
#4 d e    4  5
#5 e e    5  5
```